# Max value per group of data in R

Tags: r, group-by, max

I have a dataframe.  In this dataframe, I would like to find the max value.  Here is the data sample:

> [image: Blockquote]

I tried the following:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  max(round)
```

but received an error:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : only defined on a data frame with all
> numeric-alike variables

Both year and round are type Int.  I did try to search for this in other threads, but nothing I found resolved the issue.

I would like to receive an output that lists the Year and then the max value of the round for that year.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(year) %>% summarize(round = max(round))`

Comment: The output of `group_by` is a grouped data frame. The default behavior of the pipe operator is the output becomes the first argument of the next function. You are piping that to the function `max` and the first argument of `max` is character or numeric arguments, not a grouped data frame.

Comment: You can use most any of the answers at the "sum by group" FAQ and replace `sum` with `max`.